# Website is not scalling to mobile

Tags: mobile, scale, viewport

Ive got a problem with website which I was helping to develop. 
link is here: http://orfinstudio.pl/www/

why the website is not scalling to the size of mobile?

Ive used

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`

tried also other combinations..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem once,i got solution through internet and i fixed it,Change this in your meta tag...

content="user-scalable = yes"

Answer (score 2):

I'm fairly new to this place but I've some experience with web design and stuffs.

1. I advice you to never use templates because they can be very difficult to handle.
2. If you are using css positioning I greatly advice you use margins to move your containers around. `left`, `top`, `right`, and `bottom` will retain their property whether it's on mobile or desktop. So 
   `top:1000px(desktop) = top:1000px (mobile)`, but

   `margin-top:1000px(desktop) = margin-top:1000px/mobile screen size(mobile)`.
3. Use `px` (NOT percentages)as unit when you are directly in the body tag, mobile phones are smart, they will shrink the web page in a facinating way so you dont have to worry about multiple css for the same website(mobile queries). I advice you only use percentages in child containers, e.g a `div` in a `div`.
4. Make sure you understand how a slider works before you implement it into your website.

Finally the website looks as though its missing some style sheets,make sure you have the right paths/reference to each style or script files.

This is a mobile-desktop website which I created sometimes ago using pixels http://marybethandtonias.com